# Building Eureka Client and Server on ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, netflix-eureka

I am following this [guideline](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Building-Eureka-Client-and-Server).

I have installed git and cloned eureka. But I cannot build it.

```
gradlew clean build
```

> No command 'gradlew' found, did you mean: Command 'gradle' from
>   package 'gradle' (universe) gradlew: command not found

gradlew worked on windows successfully, ubuntu doesn't seem to recognize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gradlew is a bash script (batch script in windows) in the eureka repository, you have to use it like they mention in their guide `./gradlew clean build` don't forget the dot forward slash before `gradlew`, that's how you execute a script or a program which is not in the bin directory. If the script doesn't have the right permissions you can do this `chmod u+x gradlew.sh` or `sudo u+x gradlew.sh`.